# iOS Prevent UILabel text 'shaking' when numbers change

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I have a custom view, on top of this view I have a UILabel. The label placed in the middle of the view. The label shows current speed. The label's text size of an integer part is bigger than text size of a fractional part. I use `monospacedDigitFont` in both parts of the label's text to prevent the text shaking / moving when numbers change and `NSMutableAttributedString` to be able to set different size of the label's text. Apparently it does not work.

**The custom view:**

[image]

**Snippet of code:**

```
func updateSpeed(){
        dummySpeed += 4.0

        speedometerView.currentSpeed = speedometerView.setSmoothSpeed(SpdAv: dummySpeed)

        let myString = String(Float(round(speedometerView.currentSpeed * 10) / 10))
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: currentSpeedLabel.font.monospacedDigitFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
        attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: currentSpeedLabel.font.monospacedDigitFont.withSize(20), range: NSMakeRange(2, 1))

        currentSpeedLabel.attributedText = attrString
    }
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is not that easy if you are a newbie in iOS.
Here it is a solution:

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentSpeedLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet{
            currentSpeedLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(
                ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize * 2,
                weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
        }
    }

func updateSpeed(){
        dummySpeed += 4.0

        speedometerView.currentSpeed = speedometerView.setSmoothSpeed(SpdAv: dummySpeed)

        let myString = String(Float(round(speedometerView.currentSpeed * 10) / 10))
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(
            ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize,
            weight: UIFontWeightRegular), range: NSMakeRange(attrString.length - 1, 1))

        currentSpeedLabel.attributedText = attrString
    }
```